# Python 3 unit test fails when running at directory level

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest

I have two python unit test files in a folder

```
test/folder1/test_file1.py
test/folder2/test_file2.py
```

When I run the tests individually they pass, but when I run at the directory level the first test file passes but the second test file fails. Why would this happen? Both test files import some of the same modules. One file uses MagicMock the other doesn't

```
Pass commands
python3 -m pytest test/folder1/test_file1.py
python3 -m pytest test/folder1/test_file2.py

Fail command
python3 -m pytest test/folder1/
```

import commands in test_file1

```
import os
import shutil
import tempfile
import xlrd
from unittest import TestCase

from example.folder1 import module1
from example.folder4 import module4
```

Import commands in test_file2

```
import xlrd
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

from example.folder1 import module1 (same as test_file1)
from example.folder2 import module2
from example.folder3 import module3
import pkg_resources
```

Comment: How does it fail? What's the stack trace/output?

Comment: Most probably one of the test changes the environment in a way that the second test fails, for example by mocking an object and not setting it back after the test. Impossible to say without seeing the code, though.

Comment: `pkg_resources` is known to alter the running environment, but why not adding a [mcve] first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.

We were using a local CACHE variable. The first test was setting up the cache, the second test ended up using the cache from the first test.

Clearing the cache in setupClass() before running the second test solved the issue